# Problem in "Sign in with LinkedIn" only in one environment

Tags: java, ssl, linkedin-api

[Issue Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3hVq.png)

We are trying to "sign in with Linkedin".

Implemented the API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin

It is working fine in few of our application but the same code is not working in our dev environment - dev.badgecert.com alone

Please note the redirect URL configured in API console for dev: https://dev.badgecert.com/bc/html/linkedInSuccess.jsp

### We are getting below exception:

```
 Caught Exception while sending secure HTTP POST to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
at com.badgecert.
```

v2.util.linkedInHandle.getLinkedInProfileDetails(linkedInHandle.java:59)

Please help me to resolve this issue particularly in only one environment

Comment: This might be some deep packet inspection firewalls which is configured to prevent access to linkedin.com. It is not unusual that in corporate environments access to the internet is limited and access to social networks like linkedin might be blocked for users except marketing. Contact the local network administrators for more information.

Comment: Our network team confirmed that no firewall blocks. What else could be the reason? we are using tomcat7 n its running in linux server

Comment: I recommend that you do a packet capture to find out where the connection reset comes from and in which stage it is happening. If it occurs before or right after the initial TLS ClientHello then there is very likely some firewall involved, no matter what administrators say. It might be some firewall outside of there control though.  I recommend to check if www.linkedin.com can be accessed from the same machine in the same network outside your application, for example with curl or similar.

Comment: I logged in into dev server (linux) through putty and when i tried the below curl command it works fine (gives access token) >>                      
curl -ik -X POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken \
-d grant_type=authorization_code \
-d code=AQQCzPaduZF_ZfWs5XD4ZmVq_OfTDeFJzk28dMREra_wNciqllIVwCZRArM452PViSn8eIAWSc4jUg-iWrMi249bx5i51xVtVEFdF-PQ6benmOyaJ5zquLkLl0dIHyCtGSDrqIPg6rdr_DtAZok_r2c1sSRZ4qUuGEIgwIsXDHq4Qp18BfVaY3j7n4JSoA \
-d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.badgecert.com%2Fbc%2Fhtml%2FlinkedInSuccess.jsp \
-d client_id=75lb4khbtuo93n \
-d client_secret=xxxxxxxx